# Dart 3 Patterns Switch Case

Tags: dart, pattern-matching

This is not really a problem but a question for a more in-depth understanding. (I don't know where to ask this, if not here)

It is common knowledge that type casting (and type checks too) in any programming language require code overhead and therefore considered to be slow.

The new [Pattern system in Dart 3.0](https://dart.dev/language/patterns) allows us, to switch (so called) sealed classes.

I would like to know, how exactly the switch statement behaves in such a situation.
My studies told me, that switch expressions are a lot more performant due to (compiled to assembler) jump tables.

But how is this achieved with classes? Do they generate something like an enum which is then switched or do they really check the runtime types?

I checked the Dart repository, but don't really know where to look at.

Comment: I imagine that type checks are highly optimized in Dart... I know that in Java, they're in the order of a couple of CPU instructions (i.e. completely negligible). That said: I would also be interested if anyone knows how much performance penalty there is on a type switch VS a tradition enum switch.

Comment: We can say for sure: Computer are fast enough, you don't have to care about performance. But i am really interested in the "how" do they achieve what they offer. Honestly, i wouldn't say "A couple of CPU instructions" is completely negligible. Dart is advertising that they've reduced their needed instructions alot over time, from release to release.

Comment: Nobody knows, and nothing can be said in complete generality. It's quite possible that some switches will be more performant than others, based on how the case patterns are written. It's possible that some platforms will have different performance characteristics than others. For simple switches over a sealed set of non-generic subtypes, it's possible to be as efficient as an integer swtich. But nobody promises that it will. You should assume that it works as a sequence of type checks.

Comment: If you're worried at this level, there are probably far more low hanging fruit elsewhere.